# Does sed match the first character or not?

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to learn more about sed and I tried these examples:

```
○ → echo "four three two one" | sed 's/one/ONE/'
four three two ONE

○ → echo "abc 123" | sed 's/abc/& &/'
abc abc 123

○ → echo "abc 123" | sed 's/123/& &/'
abc 123 123

○ → echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
123 123 abc

○ → echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
 abc 123

○ → echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
abc 123
```

I'm very confused about these last two examples.  Why don't they match `123` and duplicate it, outputting `abc 123 123`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem 1

The question is why 123 is not duplicated in:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
 abc 123
```

For the answer, observe:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/&#&/'
#abc 123
```

What happens is that `[0-9]*` matches the zero-length string at the beginning of the line.

If we add the `g` flag for global replace, then, along with many zero-length strings, 123 is duplicated:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/&#&/g'
#a#b#c# 123#123
```

#### Problem 2

Again, the question is why 123 is not duplicated in this command:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
abc 123
```

The answer is that, in the default *basic regular expressions*, `+` is not an active character.  To make it active (GNU sed only), it needs to be escaped:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]\+/& &/'
abc 123 123
```

Alternatively, we can use *extended regular expressions* in which case a plain `+` is active:

```
$ echo "abc 123" | sed -E 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
abc 123 123
```

**Compatibility Note:** For old versions of GNU sed, use `-r` in place of `-E`.